# How to select Android platform in Delphi 11 Alexandria?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Using Delphi 11 Alexandria, Professional edition, w/ Patch 1 on Windows 10.

Android was selected as a platform during install, and all of the SDKs were downloaded and installed.

This works fine in Delphi 10.4, but in Delphi 11 Android is not available as a platform, even though the Platform Manager says it's installed.

Can't create a new multi-device application for anything other than Windows.

Does anyone have it working in 11?

Comment: Please read [this article](https://www.ideasawakened.com/post/quick-fix-for-for-rad-studio-11-license-failure-during-installation). The steps may help in your case.

Comment: So, just to be sure - when you create a new multi-device project, then right-click on the "Target Platforms" node in the Projects window, and then select "Add Platform", you don't get Android as an option? If you edit the `.dproj` file in a text editor, do you see a `<Platform value="Android">True</Platform>` element under `<Platforms>`? If not, add it.

Comment: Hi Remy, no only windows 64 shows up as a platform. The suggestion from Dave above was interesting but there are no slip files in the directory mentioned in the blog.  There is a .cg_license file.

Comment: This is something for Embarcadero support. You can open free support the ticket at https://www.embarcadero.com/support Choose registration and installation.

Comment: I encountered similar problem with Delphi 10.3 after upgrading from Delphi 10.1 at the time. I fixed it by using licence manager to deactivate Delphi, make a system restart and then use the licence manager to activate Delphi licence again. Note when activating you don't need to enter separate licence for Mobile platform support. Mobile platform support should be automatically added with base Delphi licence, provided you have valid Subscription for at least Delphi Professional or higher SKU.